# Multiple Inheritance with Multiple Base classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, object-oriented-analysis

please help me understand the concept of multiple inheritance here in Python (*I am from C# background which does not support multiple inheritance*).

I am using **Python 3.7.6**.

In the below code, the class `Apple` inherits the classes `ToyFruit`, `NaturalFruit`, `FakeFruit` and `RoboticFruit`. While `ToyFruit`, `NaturalFruit`, and `FakeFruit` inherit `Fruit` base class, `RoboticFruit` has a different `BaseClass` `Robot`.

I notice that the `RoboticFruit` and `Robot` are not at all getting called.

```
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("This is the Fruit __init__ function")
        self.test = "BaseClass"
        self.name = name
        print("Fruit object created")


class NaturalFruit(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("This is the NaturalFruit __init__ function")
        super().__init__(name)
        self.type = "Natural"
        print("This is a Natural Fruit")
        self.test = "NaturalClass"
        print("Natural Fruit object created")


class FakeFruit(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("This is the FakeFruit __init__ function")
        super().__init__(name)
        self.type = "Fake"
        print("This is a Fake Fruit")
        self.test = "FakeClass"
        print("Fake Fruit object created")


class ToyFruit(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("This is the ToyFruit __init__ function")
        super().__init__(name)
        self.type = "Toy"
        print("This is the Toy Fruit")
        self.test = "ToyClass"
        print("Toy Fruit object created")


class Robot:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("This is the ROBOT __init__ function")
        self.test = "RobotClass"
        self.name = name
        print("Robot object created")


class RoboticFruit(Robot):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__("RoboticFruit")
        print("Robotic Fruit")


class Apple(ToyFruit, NaturalFruit, FakeFruit, RoboticFruit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Apple")
        print("Apple object created")


apple = Apple()
# print(apple.name)
print(apple.test)
```

OUTPUT:-

```
This is the ToyFruit __init__ function
This is the NaturalFruit __init__ function
This is the FakeFruit __init__ function
This is the Fruit __init__ function
Fruit object created
This is a Fake Fruit
Fake Fruit object created
This is a Natural Fruit
Natural Fruit object created
This is the Toy Fruit
Toy Fruit object created
Apple object created
ToyClass
```

If I swap the order to

```
class Apple(RoboticFruit, ToyFruit, NaturalFruit, FakeFruit):
```

Then the `ToyFruit`, `NaturalFruit`, `FakeFruit` and `Fruit` `__init__` methods are not called at all.
I am not understanding why the `RoboticFruit` class constructors are getting skipped.

Comment: "In the below code, the class Apple inherits the classes ToyFruit, NaturalFruit, FakeFruit and RoboticFruit." - that doesn't make sense. Is an apple simultaneously a toy, natural, fake, and a robot? That doesn't sound like any apple I've ever heard of.

Comment: This concept does not apply to languages like C# and Java, but apparently this is something which does exist in Languages like Python and C++.

Is an apple simultaneously a toy, natural, fake, and a robot?
Yes. The code says so, though you should not relate it to a real world apple.

Answer (score 3):

In case of multiple inheritance, `super()` delegates to the next object in the Method Resolution Order (MRO). We can see the MRO of the class `Apple`:

```
print(Apple.__mro__)

# output:
(
<class '__main__.Apple'>, 
<class '__main__.ToyFruit'>, 
<class '__main__.NaturalFruit'>, 
<class '__main__.FakeFruit'>, 
<class '__main__.Fruit'>, 
<class '__main__.RoboticFruit'>, 
<class '__main__.Robot'>, 
<class 'object'>
)
```

So I suppose that `RoboticFruit` and `Robot` are not called because there is no call like `super().__init__(name)` in class `Fruit`, which is the previous one to `RoboticFruit` in that order (MRO). If you add a call to `super()` in `Fruit`, it should work correctly:

```
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("This is the Fruit __init__ function")
        super().__init__(name)
        self.test = "BaseClass"
        self.name = name
        print("Fruit object created")
```

Comment: Understood. But super() is in a way call to the base class/ parent. So, if we mean to call super() and this again calls RoboticFruit class, then it appears like the RoboticFruit class is the parent of Fruit class which is not true. 

Also, I tried your suggestion. On putting super() in the RoboticFruit class, it works fine. But again, if you swap the order the way it is called 
from
```class Apple(ToyFruit, NaturalFruit, FakeFruit, RoboticFruit)```
to
```class Apple(ToyFruit, NaturalFruit, FakeFruit, RoboticFruit):```

It will cease to work.I understand the MRO,but this is confusing.

Comment: In fact (if I understand well what I read in Internet) the purpose of the `super()` is to find the method is asked for by using a standard Method Resolution Order. Of course in simple inheritance `super()` calls the methods from the parent class, but in multiple-complicated inheritance it seems that's not so clear. Also, I realize that my suggestion may not work properly if we swap the order of parent classes. The only thing I can think now as an alternative is the use of hardcoded calls to parent `__init__` methods like `NaturalFruit.__init__(self, name)`.

Comment: Giannis: Did you add a call to `super()` in `Fruit`? Did it work correctly when you tested it?

Comment: @GiannisClipper I get the Robotic methods invoked when I change it according to your comment, but in a way, it shows that RoboticFruit is the parent of the Fruit class :(

Comment: @martineau Yes I've tested it and it worked for this order of the parent classes `Apple(ToyFruit, NaturalFruit, FakeFruit, RoboticFruit)` but I got an error due to `name` parameter passing when I changed the order to this one `Apple(RoboticFruit, ToyFruit, NaturalFruit, FakeFruit)`.

Comment: @undefined I've posted a second answer using hardcoded calls to `__init__` trying to keep the class hierarchy clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it returns the result you want, but it could be an option to replace `super()` calls to `__init__` with hardcoded calls:

```
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("This is the Fruit __init__ function")
        self.test = "BaseClass"
        self.name = name
        print("Fruit object created")


class NaturalFruit(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("This is the NaturalFruit __init__ function")
        Fruit.__init__(self, name)
        self.type = "Natural"
        print("This is a Natural Fruit")
        self.test = "NaturalClass"
        print("Natural Fruit object created")


class FakeFruit(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("This is the FakeFruit __init__ function")
        Fruit.__init__(self, name)
        self.type = "Fake"
        print("This is a Fake Fruit")
        self.test = "FakeClass"
        print("Fake Fruit object created")


class ToyFruit(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("This is the ToyFruit __init__ function")
        Fruit.__init__(self, name)
        self.type = "Toy"
        print("This is the Toy Fruit")
        self.test = "ToyClass"
        print("Toy Fruit object created")


class Robot:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("This is the ROBOT __init__ function")
        self.test = "RobotClass"
        self.name = name
        print("Robot object created")


class RoboticFruit(Robot):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Robot.__init__(self, "RoboticFruit")
        print("Robotic Fruit")


class Apple(ToyFruit, NaturalFruit, FakeFruit, RoboticFruit):
    def __init__(self):
        ToyFruit.__init__(self, "Apple")
        NaturalFruit.__init__(self, "Apple")
        FakeFruit.__init__(self, "Apple")
        RoboticFruit.__init__(self, "Apple")
        print("Apple object created")


apple = Apple()
#print(apple.name)
print(apple.test)

# output:
# This is the ToyFruit __init__ function
# This is the Fruit __init__ function
# Fruit object created
# This is the Toy Fruit
# Toy Fruit object created
# This is the NaturalFruit __init__ function
# This is the Fruit __init__ function
# Fruit object created
# This is a Natural Fruit
# Natural Fruit object created
# This is the FakeFruit __init__ function
# This is the Fruit __init__ function
# Fruit object created
# This is a Fake Fruit
# Fake Fruit object created
# This is the ROBOT __init__ function
# Robot object created
# Robotic Fruit
# Apple object created
# RobotClass
```

Comment: Hi @Giannis, actually I was more concerned about the weird behavior of super(). Init worked fine, I already saw that, but calling __init__ that way actually does not respect the inheritance, you can basically call any init there.
`class ToyFruit(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("This is the ToyFruit __init__ function")
        RoboticFruit.__init__(self, "Robotic Abcd")
`
This basically is explicitly calling a method from a class. Even though `Fruit` is not a `RoboticFruit`